# MLlib: Specifying null value

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

In the NOAA ISD-LITE data set, they specify a missing entry by using the special value 9999.  When using Spark MLlib, is there a way I can specify this as the na value when using na operations, such as na.drop and na.fill?

Comment: Does replacing work for you? (replace -> fill).

Comment: If you want to drop rows for each column you can use **df.filter(column.notEqual(9999))**, while if you want to replace the values you can use **df.withColumn("columnName",when(column.equalTo(9999), replacementValue).otherwise(column))**